# How to have the text cursor after the HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a `div` with `contentEditable = true`. Inside the `div` there are text nodes and some react (HTML) nodes. The code for the simple setup looks as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Tag } from "antd";
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
return (
    <div contentEditable={true} class="test-div">

     <Tag closable contentEditable={false} className="tag">
        Tag1
     </Tag>

     some-text

     <Tag closable contentEditable={false} className="tag">
        Tag2
     </Tag>

     some-text

     <Tag closable contentEditable={false} className="tag">
        Tag3
     </Tag>

    </div>
);
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here is also working fiddle : https://codesandbox.io/s/93kjq4o88r

The output looks similar to:

[image]

As you could see although the `tag` is not editable the cursor is at the tip of the tag.

I tried multiple things including:

```
.tag {
    cursor: none;
    caret-color: transparent;
}
```

but does not work the way I want. I do not want the cursor inside the `tag`. How could I do this?

Comment: Try .tag:focus { outline: none;}

Comment: I dont know what this is for but I would really warn against using contenEditable its a mess.

Comment: @EvikGhazarian Does not work

Comment: @GifCo This is for emulating a similar behavior.  Need html , text at the same time inside that looks something like a textbox.

Comment: @GifCo Getting something similar to https://pasteboard.co/IePxd5A.png

Comment: .tag {
  cursor: auto;
  caret-color: transparent;
}

Comment: @aaronlilly If you would try in the fiddle https://codesandbox.io/s/93kjq4o88r , and click after `tag3` you will see that the cursor blinks on `tag3`

Comment: sorry thought i had it working with that, but to verify, you do not want a blinking cursor correct?

Answer (score 0):

Css add:

```
.text-div{
   cursor: crosshair; //your cursor
}
```

or JS

```
document.getElementsByClassName("test-div").style.cursor = "crosshair";
```